# why is this error looks like it has a pattern? binary search C

Tags: c

im currently learning how to do binary search in C. well it worked "half-well". when i try to search for value (3,4,17,26,38) it shows the correct number of the index. but when i search for 1 or 40 or 10 or 21, it return -1 ( which is not found ), can somebody explain what is wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int binarysearch(int arr[], int n, int data);

int main ()
{
  int arr[9] = {1, 3, 4, 10, 17, 21, 26, 38, 40};
  int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
  int data = 1;

  printf("the data is located in index %d", binarysearch(arr, n, data));

  return 0;
}

int binarysearch(int arr[], int n, int data){
  int l = 0; 
  int r = n-1;

    while(l < r){
      int mid = (l + r)/2;
  
      if(data == arr[mid]){
        return mid;
      }
      else if(data > arr[mid]){
        l = mid + 1;
      }
      else {
        r = mid - 1;
      }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: A debugger would be a great tool to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can happen that `l == r` and `arr[l] == data`.

Comment: thankyou! yeah,  i actually forgot to add '<=' in the while function, so whenever its l==r, it just broke out of the while loop